# Question regarding why the vector $(a,1)^\top$ with $a$ in $\mathbb R$ is not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm currently preparing for an exam and a part of it is a multiple choice. One of the questions

$$V_1=\left\{\Big(\begin{array}\\
a\\
1\\
\end{array}
\Big) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

determine if $V_1$ is a proper vector space.

Apparently, the answer is no, but I don't quite understand, since it seems to me it fullfills all the axioms? For example, the zero vector?

$$\Big(\begin{array}\\
a\\
1\\
\end{array}\Big)+\left(-\Big(\begin{array}\\
a\\
1\\
\end{array}\Big)\right)=\Big(\begin{array}\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}\Big)$$

Why is $V_1$ not a proper vector space?

Comment: So is $(0,0)^T\in V_1$?

Comment: I don't quite understand your notation (transpose origin)? - but no, the origin is not included, but is this a requirement for all vector spaces or simply the zero vector exists by the additive inverse?

Comment: The notation $(a,b,\cdots,c)^\mathsf{T}$ is the transpose of the vector $(a,b,\cdots,c)$: column and row vectors are different objects, so we treat them differently. You're using column vectors, but we're typing row vectors because they're more visually pleasant for inline math expressions.
$$
(a,b,\cdots,c)^\mathsf{T} = \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b \\ \vdots \\ c \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: ah makes sense. I think I got it now after reading your answer. So with the additive inverse the zero vector is constructed, but is obviously not in the set, since the second component of the vector is "1". I guess it would be a vector space if it would be, say 0 or "b"?

Comment: Yup. If it were a zero, everything would be fine (you would have something that behaves more or less like $\mathbb{R}$ itself). If you let the second coordinate be any value, then you would have $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Vector spaces must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. That is, if $V$ is a vector space, then $\alpha v+\beta w \in V$ for each $v,w \in V$ and $\alpha,\beta$ in the space's field of scalars.

You have shown that, given $v := (a,1)^\mathsf{T} \in V_1$, we can take $v+(-v)$ to get $(0,0)^\mathsf{T}$.

But is $(0,0)^\mathsf{T} \in V_1$? Notice the second component of that vector: clearly, $(0,0)^\mathsf{T} \not \in V_1$.

Comment: (ignore that weird edit about a zero vector, I didn't think that one through)

Comment: Thanks. I've replied to your comment and I believe I understand it now.